# How to call angular toaster on page load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I am using [angular toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster). I would like to call the toaster function on the page load. In my HTML I have

```
  <toaster-container toaster-options="{'time-out': 3000}"></toaster-container>
```

with the example given on angular toaster page that is calling the toaster on clicking of a button, works perfectly fine, but I would like to call the toaster when the page loads. I have tried a few things like calling the toaster directly and also using the $timeout to call the toaster but both approaches don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try put the same function in the router config like

```
resolve: {
     simpleObj: function(toaster) {
          toaster.info('Home!');
    }
}
```

or put in the controller with an init() o active()

```
angular.module('app').controller(controller, controller);
    function controller(toaster) {

    active();

    function active() {
        toaster.info('Home!');
    }
```

Comment: I have tried with active() function and it doesn't work. I am not seeing any errors as well.